# iptable rule in custom chain is not effective

Tags: linux, iptables

I'm no iptables expert and have 2 strange behaviors that needs fixing !

## Problem 1 : Why am I not banned ?

I have a custom chain `f2b-nginx-naxsi` which has the following iptable rules:

```
$ sudo iptables -S f2b-nginx-naxsi
-N f2b-nginx-naxsi
-A f2b-nginx-naxsi -s 81.250.100.81/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable #<== Here
-A f2b-nginx-naxsi -j RETURN
```

`81.250.100.81` is my public IP so I should be banned.

**Its not working. The rule is innefective !**

The chain is loaded from the `INPUT` chain as follow:

```
sudo iptables -S INPUT
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -j f2b-nginx-naxsi    #<== Here
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

## Problem 2 : Why am I banned from SSH and not :80 ?

In order to fix *problem 1* I took the previous rule and set it inside the `INPUT`chain:
`-I INPUT -s 81.250.100.81/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable`

After pressing enter I got disconnected from the machine, lol.
But for some reasons I still can ping our nginx from the browser...
**Why did it kill SSH (22) but not standard http connections (80)**

Thx in advance,
;-)

Comment: You should add the whole output of `iptables-save` to your question.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Well... I won't show all the iptables for security reasons but if you want to look at something in particular I would happily edit my question ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly got to the bottom of the mystery !

**The problem comes from docker which is overiding my iptable rule...**

In order to drop incoming connection to a docker container you must place your rule inside a chain nammed `DOCKER-USER`.
This chain is created by Docker itself and those rules will take precedence over the ones from docker engine.

For instance, to ban a specific IP *(from fail2ban for example)* on port 443 :

`sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -s <SPECIFIC_IP> -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP`

(Change `eth0` to whatever is your external interface)

- Don't forget to set a port or the rule might apply on your SSH port (22) and you will ban yourself...
- Adding a rule to the `INPUT` chain won't work if you are trying to block the access to a docker container.
- The chain called `DOCKER` is for docker stuff only. Don't put anything in there.

Answer (score 0):

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Check that the multiport iptables module is loaded:

   ```
    lsmod | grep multiport
    # Should see something like xt_multiport or ipt_multiport in the output
   ```
2. Verify that your nginx server is actually listening on port 80 and or 443. You could be configured behind a proxy.

   ```
    sudo ss -tlnp | grep nginx
    # Should see nginx listed listening on one of those two ports
   ```

(edited)

2b. Check which port(s) on your docker host are mapped to the nginx container.

```
    docker port <container_name>

This command should show which port(s) you need to use in your custom IPtables chain running on the container host.
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. (1) got xt_multiport ! (2) does not return anything. I guess its because our nginx is in docker... The nginx works as it is being used to access applications just fine.

Comment: @Doctor Did you run the `ss` command on the docker host or container? Are your iptables rules running on the docker container or host as well?

Comment: I ran the cmd on the host. The ss command is not availble inside the container.

Comment: @Doctor The iptables rules in your custom table need to map to the correct host port. There are most likely several more layers of networking involved in your setup. Answer edited.

Comment: `80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:80` and `443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:443`. Seems correct to me as the iptable rule blocks 80 and 443. It was a good idea though !