# I6ptables rule to block docker containers from accessing interface

Tags: iptables, docker, firewall, ipv6, ip6tables

### Context:

- Multiple docker containers listening on all interfaces
- wireguard `wg0` interface with an IPv6 address
- eventually, NFS serving files to `wg0` clients

### Issue:

Clients behind `wg0` can access these containers. I would like to avoid that, as well as docker container accessing hosts behind that interface.

The simplest way to filter them out would be to drop packets between docker containers and the wireguard interface. However, the following rule didn't work:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i wg0 -j DROP
```

I wasn't sure why when I first wrote this question, but it turns out `wg0` only uses IPv6 addresses, so I would need to use a `ip6tables` rule instead, but it looks like the `DOCKER-USER` chain isn't present there.

---

**Related questions**: [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607376/176127) used the wrong input chain. [That one](https://serverfault.com/questions/1030012/block-incoming-traffic-thru-external-interface-to-docker-containers-on-dc-osmes) is essentially the same question, but is formulated in an apache-mesos specific way, which I didn't want to change.

---

#### Additional context and solutions considered

- Arguably, this is a firewall issue, but I would like to know why the iptable rule doesn't work.
- This exclusion rule can likely be specified using `nftables` or another BPF tool. I'd be curious regarding the syntax
- Namespaces could work. I have many more questions on them, but avoiding them is probably wise while wg-quick doesn't support those, for simplicity. I am not sure that would interact with NFS either.
- I could try to block IP ranges from wireguard hosts. That sounds more complex and harder to maintain.
- Container services could listen on specific IPs. It sounds less flexible and harder to maintain.

Comment: Can you post iptables -vnL ? Isn't DOCKER-USER custom chain part of FORWARD chain ?

Comment: Ah, thanks to your comment I just realized `iptables` only supports IPv4, and I use IPv6 everywhere. It also seems like `DOCKER-USER` isn't present for `ip6tables`. `DOCKER-USER` seems completely separate from the `FORWARD` chain on that output.